# How to render one association automatically with cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have cocoon working with nested form, if you click add field link it inserts input fields. How do I render first input automatically, and then insert additional inputs when "add field" is clicked ?

Answer (score 7):

In your controller, use this code.  In the code below, jobs is a model and profile accepts_nested_attributes_for jobs. Replace @profile with whatever your form is for.  The 2nd line is what will build the form fields, unless form fields already exist.

```
def new
    @profile = current_user.profile
    1.times {@profile.jobs.build} unless current_user.profile.jobs.any?
end
```

You may need to change times to time since its singular.  In fact, you may be able to get rid of the times method altogether and do:

```
def new
    @profile = current_user.profile
    @profile.jobs.build unless current_user.profile.jobs.any?
end
```

Comment: Thanks. In profile controller - 1.times {@profile.jobs.tasks} gives me undefined method `tasks' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations ... error

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty solution is to just use jQuery (which Cocoon requires anyways) to click Cocoon's "add item" button when the page loads:

`$(document).ready(function() { $(".add_fields").click() } );`

I use this in my "new" views, but not in "edit" views, since there may already be some nested items and I don't want to make assumptions. But you could also use script to count the nested item forms and conditionally show the "new item" fields.

Comment: This is great if your nested fields appear after you do something in the screen.